# How to convert "2020-12-20T00:00:00.000Z" to java.util.Date?

Tags: java, date, localdate, datetime-parsing, datetimeformatter

I tried to use

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.ENGLISH);
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(d.toString(), formatter);
```

but it throws an error.

Is there any way to convert the JSON default timestamp?

Comment: What error does it throw, exactly?

Comment: Don't use `java.util.Date` if you can avoid it. Use `Instant` instead.

Comment: I was using it for Hibernate

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60214805/2513200 (as your format seems to be ISO compliant)

Comment: That said, if this is comming from JSON, your JSON parser library may also provide a function for this.

Comment: @user1688726 - If one of the answers resolved your issue, you can help the community by marking that as accepted. An accepted answer helps future visitors use the solution confidently.

Answer (score 8):

You need to use `LocalDateTime`.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = 
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.ENGLISH);
LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.parse(d.toString(), formatter);
```

Answer (score 4):

### You do not need `DateTimeFormatter` to parse your date-time string

Parse the given date string directly to `OffsetDateTime`. The modern date-time API is based on [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and does not require using a `DateTimeFormatter` object explicitly as long as the date-time string conforms to the ISO 8601 standards. The `Z` in your date-time string is the [timezone designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) for zero-timezone offset. It stands for Zulu and specifies the `Etc/UTC` timezone (which has the timezone offset of `+00:00` hours).

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2020-12-20T00:00:00.000Z");
```

### Convert the `OffsetDateTime` into `Instant`

Convert the `OffsetDateTime` into `Instant` using [`OffsetDateTime#toInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#toInstant--). An [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) represents an instantaneous point on the timeline. It is independent of a timezone and thus, it is always in UTC.

```
Instant instant = odt.toInstant();
```

### Stop using the legacy date-time API

With the release of Java SE 8 in March 2014, the outdated and error-prone legacy date-time API (`java.util` date-time types and their formatting type, `SimpleDateFormat` etc.) was supplanted by `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup>. It is strongly recommended to stop using the legacy API and switch to this new API. If at all, you need `java.util.Date`, get it using [`java.util.Date#from(Instant)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#from-java.time.Instant-).

```
java.util.Date date = Date.from(instant);
```

Note that the `java.util.Date` object is not a real date-time object like the [modern date-time types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html); rather, it represents the number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as "the epoch", namely `January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT` (or UTC). When you print an object of `java.util.Date`, its `toString` method returns the date-time in the JVM's timezone, calculated from this milliseconds value. If you need to print the date-time in a different timezone, you will need to set the timezone to `SimpleDateFormat` and obtain the formatted string from it e.g.

```
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX", Locale.ENGLISH);
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
```

### You can convert an `Instant` to other date-time types

You can convert an `Instant` to other date-time types easily e.g. if you want to convert it into a `ZonedDateTime` instance representing the date-time in London, you can do so as

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"));
```

### `LocalDateTime` is useless in your case

[Quoted below](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/datetime.html) is a very good description of the uses of `LocalDateTime`:

> This class can be used to represent a specific event, such as the
> first race for the Louis Vuitton Cup Finals in the America's Cup
> Challenger Series, which began at 1:10 p.m. on August 17, 2013. Note
> that this means 1:10 p.m. in local time.

The best use of your date-time string is as an `OffsetDateTime` which you have obtained in the first step itself.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Parse the date-time string into OffsetDateTime
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2020-12-20T00:00:00.000Z");
        System.out.println(odt);

        // Convert OffsetDateTime into Instant
        Instant instant = odt.toInstant();

        // If at all, you need java.util.Date
        Date date = Date.from(instant);
        System.out.println(date);

        // You can convert an `Instant` to other date-time types easily
        // e.g. to ZoneDateTime in a specific timezone
        ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"));
        System.out.println(zdt);

        // e.g. to OffsetDateTime with a specific timezone offset
        OffsetDateTime odt0530 = instant.atOffset(ZoneOffset.of("-05:30"));
        System.out.println(odt0530);

        // e.g. to LocalDateTime via an OffsetDateTime or a ZonedDateTime
        LocalDateTime ldt = odt.toLocalDateTime();
        System.out.println(ldt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-12-20T00:00Z
Sun Dec 20 00:00:00 GMT 2020
2020-12-20T00:00Z[Europe/London]
2020-12-19T18:30-05:30
2020-12-20T00:00
```

Learn more about `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Comment: Instant class only available on Android 26 and above. if you are looking for backward compatibility , you need to stick with SimpleDateFormat only.

Answer (score 3):

To your question on how to convert `LocalDate` to `java.util.Date`, you can use `Date.from` method as follows. Let me know if that is what you are expecting to achieve.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.ENGLISH);
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse("2020-12-20T00:00:00.000Z", formatter);
Date date = Date.from(localDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
System.out.println(date);
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Z` is the Zulu time-zone (i.e. the UTC time-zone), not a literal Z.

This whole format is the ISO-8601 instant format.

There is a pre-existing formatter for that: [DateTimeFormatter#ISO_INSTANT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_INSTANT)

Extract from the javadoc:

> public static final DateTimeFormatter ISO_INSTANT
>
> The ISO instant formatter that formats or parses an instant in UTC, such as '2011-12-03T10:15:30Z'.
>
> This returns an immutable formatter capable of formatting and parsing the ISO-8601 instant format. When formatting, the second-of-minute is always output. The nano-of-second outputs zero, three, six or nine digits digits as necessary. When parsing, time to at least the seconds field is required. Fractional seconds from zero to nine are parsed. The localized decimal style is not used.
>
> This is a special case formatter intended to allow a human readable form of an Instant. The Instant class is designed to only represent a point in time and internally stores a value in nanoseconds from a fixed epoch of 1970-01-01Z. As such, an Instant cannot be formatted as a date or time without providing some form of time-zone. This formatter allows the Instant to be formatted, by providing a suitable conversion using ZoneOffset.UTC.
>
> The format consists of:
>
> The ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME where the instant is converted from ChronoField.INSTANT_SECONDS and ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND using the UTC offset. Parsing is case insensitive.
>
> The returned formatter has no override chronology or zone. It uses the STRICT resolver style.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be default format, please try this one.

```java
ZonedDateTime dateTime  = ZonedDateTime.parse("2020-07-28T14:28:52.877Z");

// In case you still need LocalDateTime
LocalDateTime localDateTime  = dateTime.toLocalDateTime();
```